# Error while running 'glance image-create' command

Tags: 14.04, openstack, disk-image

While issuing the command:

"glance image-create --name "cirros" --file cirros-0.3.3-x86_64-disk.img --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --is-public True --progress"

I got the following error message:-

'You must provide a username via either --os-username or env[OS_USERNAME]'

What should I do..? I'm runnign ubuntu 14.04

I'm new to ubuntu, please help

Regards,

--V

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# nano /etc/glance/policy.json
```

In the open file change the following line:

```
"publicize_image": "role:admin",
```

With:

```
"publicize_image": "",
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Close nano.

Then restart glance:

```
# glance-control all restart
```

## [Source](http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2014/10/30/openstack-glance-allow-user-to-create-public-images/)

Comment: Thanks I tried it ... the policy.json file says "publicize_image": "",. I tried with both the options "publicize_image": "", & "publicize_image": "admin", with same result ... I keep getting "publicURL endpoint for image not found"

Comment: ... I tried your solution plus I tried the solution listed in __http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/glance-verify.html__ but nothing seems to work. I keep getting "publicURL endpoint for image not found". Please help..

Comment: nano admin-openrc.sh
 export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
 export OS_USERNAME=admin
 export OS_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
 export OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller:35357/v2.0

source admin-openrc.sh

wget -P /tmp/images http://download.cirros-cloud.net/0.3.3/cirros-0.3.3-x86_64-disk.img

glance image-create --name "cirros-0.3.3-x86_64" --file /tmp/images/cirros-0.3.3-x86_64-disk.img --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --is-public True --progress

Error:- publicURL endpoint for image not found

Answer (score 0):

I just copied @MaxLobur's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20354904):

If you used devstack (http://devstack.org/) to deploy OpenStack you can use openrc trick:

```
$cd devstack/
$source openrc admin admin # for admin rights
```

or

```
$source openrc demo demo # for demo user
```

Otherwise you need to export OS variables manually:

```
$export OS_USERNAME = admin
$export OS_TENANT_NAME = <yourtenant>
$export OS_PASSWORD = <yourpasswd> # password which you used during deployment etc
```

Comment: @kyodake   I did 'source admin-openrc.sh', which when I open with nano command, I get 4 variables:
"export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller:35357/v2.0"

Even then command glance image-create returns with an error "publicURL endpoint for image not found"